# Difference between C++ dlls and Delphi dlls

Tags: delphi, dll

Is there a real difference between C++ dlls and Delphi dlls?
A application loads only C++ dlls.
Changing calling convention to cdecl is of no use
Is there a way to find whether a dll is a C++ dll?
What is the advantage of that dll?
I mean a Delphi dll can have parameters and/or return type of Delphi.
Like that C++ dll may have some exclusive data type/

Thanks for any hint

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to examine a DLL and determine calling conventions.  Also, you can export C functions from C++, but you can't export classes (and expect any sort of compatibility between compilers, even different builds or versions of the same compiler)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I programatically deduce the calling convention used by a C++ dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277986/can-i-programatically-deduce-the-calling-convention-used-by-a-c-dll)

Comment: What are you trying to do? You shouldn't care or even need to know what language was used to implement a DLL that you link to.

Comment: I'd say that the key here is that the DLL calling app may be looking for specific vtables as exports, so it may not work. Look for "decorated names" in the DLL examples you have. Such is poor design, but not uncommon.

Answer (score 8):

C++ dlls can, of course, use or expose C++-specific items (C++ classes, template functions, etc.), and a Delphi DLL could expose Delphi-specific items (sets, strings, etc.). But if both are written properly, and only use things other languages can use too, there should be no difference.

Fact is that not all C++ or Delphi DLLs are written properly. Also the default calling convention in Delphi is `register` (`__fastcall` in C++Builder), while C and C++ by default use `cdecl`. But generally both languages should use `stdcall`.

The only way to use a DLL is to either get a header file (.h) for it, or a Delphi import unit. The .h file can be translated into an import unit. If you only have a DLL but none of these, it doesn't make much sense to try to guess the parameters of functions.

If you look at the DLL with TDUMP.exe or Dependency Walker, you might get a hint, as was said in another answer. Dependency on e.g. msvcrtXX.dll might be a good hint it is a C++ DLL.

You might also try to get a .tlb from the DLL. You can do this in the IDE (From memory: "Component menu" - "import component" or some such).

If you want to know the calling convention, read [this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#cconvs), especially the part about finding out the calling convention.

**Addition**

Some C++ programmers forget to wrap their declarations in `extern "C"` blocks, so the exported functions are mangled. This could tell you which parameters are required, but you get ugly names. For this, Dependency Walker is a great help, as it can translate them (for VC++ generated or compatible DLLs at least). It makes using those functions from a different C++ compiler or a C compiler pretty hard, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dependency Walker to examine the functions in DLLs:

http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: But IIRC that won't tell if it is a C++ dll. OK, a call to msvcrt might be a hint, but it doesn't have to be. I have written Delphi code that used it too.

Comment: DLLs should be language agnostic.  All you need to know is the name of the exported function and the parametesr/return types.

Comment: DLLs should be, but are far too often not, especially if they are made by people who only know their language. I have helped with quite a few translations of DLLs that were not.